# Blender objects locked to view when being added

Tags: objects

Whenever I add new objects, it adds the in a way that the rotation is locked to the view and I have to manually set it to (0, 0, 0). Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 3):

On the <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Editing</kbd> tab make sure that you have <kbd>World</kbd> set against <kbd>Align</kbd><kbd>To</kbd> under New Objects. It sounds as if you have it set to <kbd>View</kbd>.

[image]

Don't forget to save the preferences (bottom left icon).